# Nodejs Webpack Breaking Change

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-5

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meA5Y.jpg)

I have Uniswap Clone project and when i start the project i get this module error. can someone who knows please help?

Methods I've tried:

*npm audit --fix

*npm install cipher-base

*add webpack.config.js

Error Code:

> ```
> Compiled with problems:X
>
> ERROR in ../../node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 2:16-43
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\nzl swap 1.0\my-eth-app\node_modules\cipher-base'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>   - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
>   - install 'stream-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
>   resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
>
>
> ERROR in ../../node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 7:193-227
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\nzl swap 1.0\my-eth-app\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>   - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
>   - install 'crypto-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
>   resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
>
>
> ERROR in ../../node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 27:74-91
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\nzl swap 1.0\my-eth-app\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\lib'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>   - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
>   - install 'crypto-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
>   resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
>
>
> ERROR in ../../node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 5:193-227
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\nzl swap 1.0\my-eth-app\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>   - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
>   - install 'crypto-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
>   resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
>
>
> ERROR in ../../node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 26:11-26
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\nzl swap 1.0\my-eth-app\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>   - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
>   - install 'stream-http'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
>   resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
>
>
> ERROR in ../../node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 27:12-28
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\nzl swap 1.0\my-eth-app\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>   - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
>   - install 'https-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
>   resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
> ```

Package.json:

> ```
> {
>   "name": "@my-app/monorepo",
>   "version": "1.0.0",
>   "keywords": [
>     "ethereum",
>     "react",
>     "workspaces",
>     "yarn"
>   ],
>   "private": true,
>   "scripts": {
>     "react-app:build": "yarn workspace @my-app/react-app build",
>     "react-app:eject": "yarn workspace @my-app/react-app eject",
>     "react-app:ipfs": "yarn workspace @my-app/react-app ipfs",
>     "react-app:start": "yarn workspace @my-app/react-app start",
>     "react-app:test": "yarn workspace @my-app/react-app test"
>   },
>   "workspaces": {
>     "packages": [
>       "packages/*"
>     ]
>   },
>   "resolutions": {
>     "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
>   },
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "@babel/core": "^7.20.5",
>     "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
>     "assert": "^2.0.0",
>     "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
>     "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
>     "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
>     "buffer": "^6.0.3",
>     "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
>     "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
>     "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
>     "process": "^0.11.10",
>     "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
>     "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
>     "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
>     "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
>     "url": "^0.11.0",
>     "webpack": "^5.75.0",
>     "webpack-config": "^7.0.0",
>     "webpack-fix-style-only-entries": "^0.6.1"
>   },
>   "dependencies": {
>     "cipher-base": "^1.0.4",
>     "ipfs-deploy": "12.0.1",
>     "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
>     "swr": "^2.0.0",
>     "util": "^0.12.5"
>   }
> }
> ```

> I tried the solutions on sites such as overflow, but I could not find the solution.

Comment: https://github.com/crypto-browserify/cipher-base/issues/10#issuecomment-890863187 This seems to solve the problem. Let me know if it works.

Comment: this method didn't work, do you know any other method?